# Access Recycle Bin from the Explorer window

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, shortcuts, recycle-bin

How can I access the Recycle Bin from the Explorer window?

Many times I have a lot of windows open and do not wish to minimize them just to get to the Recycle Bin so <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is not desired.

I know I can start typing "recycle" in the search bar but just assume I wish to avoid that.

[image]

Comment: Shortcut to `%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe /N,::{645FF040-5081-101B-9F08-00AA002F954E}` [source](https://www.digitalred.com/notes/windows-explorer-paths/)

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeDXc.png) answer from the duplicate also applies to Windows 10.  Somebody might consider submitting an answer to the duplicate question, by suggesting you can pin the Recycle Bin to the Quick Access.  There are multiple answers suggesting the Task Bar but none that suggest quick access.

Comment: type in the addressbar: `shell:recyclebinfolder` see this list for all shell: shortcuts: https://ss64.com/nt/shell.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I access the Recycle Bin from the Explorer window?

You can add the Recycle Bin to File Explorer Quick Access.

Open Recycle Bin.  Right click Quick Access in Recycle Bin.  Select Pin Current Folder to QA.

This works in Windows 10 and Windows 11.

Reference:

[Add Recycle Bin to the Quick Access list](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/add-recycle-bin-to-quick-access-in-file-explorer.html#:%7E:text=Steps%20to%20add%20Recycle%20Bin%20to%20Quick%20access,current%20folder%20to%20Quick%20access%20from%20the%20menu.)

You can also place the Recycle Bin on the Task Bar if you wish.  Create a new folder on the Task Bar and rename it Recycle Bin.  Drag the Recycle Bin to the Task Bar.

This is for Windows 10.

Reference:

[Recycle Bin on Windows 10 Task Bar](https://www.alphr.com/add-recycle-bin-windows-10-taskbar/)

Comment: Pinning it to "Quick Access" is excellent, thank you!